# How do I change the height and width of an image in an <i> tag using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I would like to change the height and the width of flags in the `<i>` tag.

The images of the flags are showing properly.

However, I would like to resize them since they are quite small which is not working.

I would really appreciate any help.

This example is from: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/content/flag/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="flag.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            i {
                width: 150px;
                height: 100px;
            }

            #flag {
                height: 150px;
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flag">
            <i class="ae flag"></i>
        </div>
        <i class="france flag"></i>
        <i class="myanmar flag"></i>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are the flags icon-font?

Comment: you can not do that because all flags are croped from here https://mdbootstrap.com/img/svg/flags.png

Comment: I am not sure. I have tried the attribute `font-size` but it is still the same.

Comment: @abdelhedihlel How do I go about changing the size. Is there any other place where I can do similar thing and get bigger size images?

Comment: You cannot, I think. They do it in a poor way.

Comment: @mrkn0007 you can use this https://www.phoca.cz/cssflags/#examples

Comment: CSS can let it become bigger `transform: scale(2);`, but it will become blur.

Comment: Yes, it does blur. @rangerz Is there any other css library that you can recommend?

Comment: @abdelhedihlel I found https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css. I am going to try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all who contributed and helped me learn so much.

With all of the information provided by the helpful community, the following solution worked best for me:

CSS:

```
.a1{

  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
}

.b1{
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="a1" src="https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/gb.svg">
<img class="b1" src="https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/pk.svg">
```

Since, it is a SVG I am referencing, I can easily scale it up without worrying about the  blurriness or pixels.

Thank you again for everyone that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize the Mdbootstrap icons. I saw the link you provided in question; you should read **types section** on this page, they mentioned that you can't resize the icon.

[image: this page]

Solution for this is you have to use flag image and provide link to image with anchor tag.`

```html
 <a href="#">
 <img  src="image.jpeg" height="30" width="30" alt=""/>
 </a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I read the specifications but I was just wondering if there was any other way to scale the flags up. I have found the solution to this and have posted it as an answer.